# How to hide existing folder in Android?

Tags: java, android, file, io, android-file

I have a existing folder (Old Folder name : xyz) in Sdcard, Whenever I try to rename this folder (New Folder name : .xyz) using toRename(). It return false and create a new folder (name : .xyz). Old Folder (name : xyz) is also visible in sdcard.

How to rename the existing folder to make a that Folder hidden in Android?

```
String dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/xyz";

File file = new File(dir);
StringdirHide = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/.xyz";
File fileHide = new File(dirHide);
if (!file.exists() && !fileHide.exists())
{
    fileHide.mkdir();
}
else if(file.exists())
{
    file.toRename(fileHide);
}
```

Comment: can you post the code .. ?

Comment: why you have put .   in  /.xyz

Comment: have you specified write external storage permission into manifest file?

Comment: @AndroidWeblineindia I have gave write external storage permission into manifest file

Comment: Ok please refer my answer that i have given

Answer (score 1):

The method to rename is **renameTo**. The following code should work. Tell me if you face any problems.

```
String dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/xyz";

File file = new File(dir);
String dirHide = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/.xyz";
File fileHide = new File(dirHide);
if (file.exists() && !fileHide.exists()) {
    file.renameTo(fileHide);
} else if(!file.exists()) {
    fileHide.mkdir();
}
```

Comment: I have used renameTo(), it created new folder (name : .xyz) and also show old folder (name : xyz)

Answer (score 0):

@Akashsingla19 I think problem is the folder u want to rename is not exist run following code **Twice** hope you will get your answer

```
if (!file.exists())
        {
            file.mkdir();
        }
        else if(file.exists())
        {
            file.renameTo(fileHide);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are using some **`toRename()`** method, which i couldn't found anywhere in `File` class in android. Actual method of `File` class in android to rename folders and files is [renameTo()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#renameTo(java.io.File)). Check this method and try to use it and revert please.

Thanks.